# Missing FilePond instance methods from react-JS?

Tags: reactjs, instance, filepond

I am trying to use FilePond in my typescript React project and I am finding that a lot of the instructions from FilePond's tutorials do not work as expected.

I am following the tutorial at https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/frameworks/react/ and I am interested in the part about able to call instance methods.

This line is supposed to create a reference to a FilePond object

```
<FilePond ref={ref => this.pond = ref} ...
```

However, I get an error saying this.pond does not exist, so I try to initialize an instance beforehand.

```
const pond = FilePond.create();
```

My editor (Visual Studio Code) tells me FilePond.create() does not exist.  None of the listed methods at https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/filepond-instance/#methods exist.  What could I be missing here?